# My linked list isn't adding properly (keeps replacing 3rd position) - c

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, singly-linked-list

It seems to add the first mapList node, then add the node following it fine, but every node added after that gets put in that third position every single time even though it seems like my *next's are being set correctly (I'm still new at pointers and C)  which is causing me my segmentation error when I want to access the further nodes.  I've got the patronNode adding working which was far more complicated, I can't seem to get this one right and those outputting just spit blasphemy at me =(

here are the two structures..

```
struct bookMap
{
    int totalBooks;
    char key[AUTHOR_NAME_LEN];
    struct bookMap *next;
    struct bookNode *bList,*newBNode;
 };


 struct Library{
    int totalPatrons, totalBooks;
    struct patronNode       *pList,*newPNode;
    struct bookMap          *mapList,*newMapNode;
  };
```

here's the add Func

```
int addMapNode(struct Book *b, struct Library *lib)
{
     struct bookMap *newKey;
     printf("\nENTERING ADDMAPNODE WITH KEY = %s\n",b->author);
     if(lib->totalBooks == 0)//NO CURRENT BOOKS
     {
            lib->totalBooks++;
            newKey = (struct bookMap *) malloc(sizeof(struct bookMap));
            strcpy(newKey->key,b->author);  //set the first map node key
            addBookToCollection(b,newKey);  //add the book to our first map node
            lib->mapList = newKey;
            return(0);
    }else
    {
            if((isKey(b,&newKey,lib->mapList)) == 0)
            {
                    addBookToCollection(b,newKey);
            }else
            {
                    struct bookMap *walker;
                    walker = lib->mapList;
                    for(;;)
                    {
                            if(walker->next == NULL)
                            {
                                    printf("Adding a key after %s\n",walker->key);
                                    lib->totalBooks++;
                                    newKey=(struct bookMap *) malloc(sizeof(struct bookMap));
                                    strcpy(newKey->key,b->author);
                                    addBookToCollection(b,newKey);
                                    newKey->next = NULL;
                                    walker->next = newKey;
                                    printf("added %s\n",walker->next->key);
                                    return(0);
                            }
                            printf("current key is %s\n",walker->key);
                            walker = walker->next;
                    }
```

Here is what my output looks like:

ENTERING ADDMAPNODE WITH KEY = Orson Scott Card

ENTERING ADDMAPNODE WITH KEY = Frank Herbert - 
Adding a key after Orson Scott Card - 
added Frank Herbert

ENTERING ADDMAPNODE WITH KEY = Isaac Asimov
 - current key is Orson Scott Card
 - Adding a key after Frank Herbert
 - added Isaac Asimov

ENTERING ADDMAPNODE WITH KEY = Douglas Adams
 - current key is Orson Scott Card
 - Adding a key after Frank Herbert
 - added Douglas Adams

ENTERING ADDMAPNODE WITH KEY = George Orwell
 - current key is Orson Scott Card
 - Adding a key after Frank Herbert
 - added George Orwell

ENTERING ADDMAPNODE WITH KEY = Robert A. Heinlein
 - current key is Orson Scott Card
 - Adding a key after Frank Herbert
 - added Robert A. Heinlein

ENTERING ADDMAPNODE WITH KEY = Ray Bradbury
 - current key is Orson Scott Card
 - Adding a key after Frank Herbert
 - added Ray Bradbury

ect....  every key's added after Frank Herbert, because the code thinks that Herbert's->next is NULL, even though i JUST made it = to a new node...  CONFIZZZLED

Comment: Would you attach the output of the program please?

Comment: Can your example be shorter? And show the structures you are using? http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 0):

You should include the `struct bookMap` definition, <s>but I believe your problem is the `strcpy` calls: you haven't allocated any space for the `->key` fields</s>.

One issue is you fail to set `->next = NULL` for the first node, but if that actually mattered here you'd get to the `"current key is "` line unexpectedly rather than what is seen.

So `walker->next == NULL` every time, after the first, and yet it is fine when the `"added "` line executes.

I'd check the code of `isKey` and make sure it is not destroying the `->next` pointers.

Comment: Hey, thanks.  I added up the structs to help, i think since key is just a char array I'm safe for allocating since it should grow with bookMap (i think)